# Building for iOS if registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios8, xcode6

If there are breaking changes with how devices register for notifications, and we cannot use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: anymore, how can we build a new version of the app to support iOS 8 if we cannot use Xcode 6 beta?  Will we have to build and submit the day the Xcode 6 GM version is released for our users to continue to get push notifications?

Comment: Why can't you use the xcode 6 beta?

Comment: Can we use the xcode 6 beta and submit to the app store?  I was under the impression that Apple will not accept builds from a beta version of xcode.

Comment: The method doesn't work for ios8 but will still work on ios 7. Build in xcode 6 beta, and then when GA version is out compile and submit that way. You are correct that you can only submit for ios 8 apps once the sdk is out of beta. Existing users will continue to get push notifications since their tokens won't be invalidated I believe

Answer (score 50):

iOS 8 has changed notification registration. So you need to check device version and then you need to register notification settings.(please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=713#713) link.)
I try this code on Xcode 6 and its worked for me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }

     return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Julldar thanks for comment. I edit my content. Please edit your advice. Because this code is working.

Comment: I never said it's not working :). I actually just asked for some clarifications, which you did, so it's great :). I'll actually delete the other comment :) and this one in a little while so as not to cluster SO

Answer (score 17):

You might want to consider using respondsToSelector rather than checking the system version:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
#endif
```

Comment: Should be `UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge`.

Answer (score 3):

As per Apple documentation `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` is deprecated in iOS 8 instead you can use `registerForRemoteNotifications` and `registerUserNotificationSettings:`.

Xcode 6 beta and iOS 8 beta are pre-release softwar. Beta versions are for development and testing only. New apps and app updates must be built with release versions of Xcode and iOS to submit to the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([[[ UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) 
    {
        // for iOS 8
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // for iOS < 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

    // RESET THE BADGE COUNT 
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]) {
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
 }
        else {
UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
  }    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```