# Is registerForRemoteNotificationTypes still working on ios 10?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

It is quite related to this problem.

[Building for iOS if registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147454/building-for-ios-if-registerforremotenotificationtypes-is-not-supported-in-ios)

For all my latest app, I have already changed the way app register push token.

But I have very old app (in 2014). It just use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes. I notice that device can't register push token already.(it is on app store since 2014)

Is that correct behaviour? Do I have to update my app? I thought apple would still support for backward compatibility.

Comment: Have you checked your APNS certificates? They are issued for a year.

Comment: yes. It is still valid. My app in ios 8 and 9 are still okay. Only ios 10 got issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype